# Some weights of Actor Critic model not updating

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am working on an Actor-Critic model in Pytorch. The model first receives the input in an RNN and then the policy net comes into play. The code for Policy net is:

```
class Policy(nn.Module):
    """
    implements both actor and critic in one model
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(Policy, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(state_size+1, 128)

        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)

        # actor's layer
        self.action_head = nn.Linear(64, action_size)
        self.mu = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.var = nn.Softplus()

        # critic's layer
        self.value_head = nn.Linear(64, 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        """
        forward of both actor and critic
        """
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))

        # actor: choses action to take from state s_t 
        # by returning probability of each action
        action_prob = self.action_head(x)
        mu = self.mu(action_prob)
        var = self.var(action_prob)

        # critic: evaluates being in the state s_t
        state_values = self.value_head(x)

        return mu, var, state_values
policy = Policy()
```

In model class, we are calling this policy after the rnn. And in agent class’s act method, we are calling the model to get the action like this:

```
 def act(self, some_input, state):
      mu, var, state_value = self.model(some_input, state)
      mu = mu.data.cpu().numpy()
      sigma = torch.sqrt(var).data.cpu().numpy()
      action = np.random.normal(mu, sigma)
      action = np.clip(action, 0, 1)
      action = torch.from_numpy(action/1000)
      return action, state_value
```

I must mention that in optimizer, we are calling the model.parameters. When we print all the trainable parameters in each epoch, we see that everything else is changing except for the policy.action_head. Any idea why this is happening? I must also mention how the losses are calculated now:

```
       advantage = reward - Value
       Lp = -math.log(pdf_prob_now)*advantage
       policy_losses.append(Lp)
       #similar for value_losses
#after all the runs in the epoch is done
loss = torch.stack(policy_losses).sum() + alpha*torch.stack(value_losses).sum()
loss.backward()
```

Here Value is the state_value (the 2nd output from agent.act) and the pdf_prob_now is the probability of the action from all possible actions which is calculated like this:

```
def find_pdf(policy, action, rnn_output):
    mu, var, _ = policy(rnn_output)
    mu = mu.data.cpu().numpy()
    sigma = torch.sqrt(var).data.cpu().numpy()
    pdf_probability = stats.norm.pdf(action.cpu(), loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    return pdf_probability
```

Is there some logical error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the bug is in `act` function

```py
def act(self, some_input, state):
    # mu contains info required for gradient
    mu, var, state_value = self.model(some_input, state)
    # mu is detached and now has forgot all the operations performed
    # in self.action_head
    mu = mu.data.cpu().numpy()
    sigma = torch.sqrt(var).data.cpu().numpy()
    action = np.random.normal(mu, sigma)
    action = np.clip(action, 0, 1)
    action = torch.from_numpy(action/1000)
    return action, state_value
```

for the further process, if loss is calculated using tensor operations performed on `action`, it can not be traced back to update `self.action_head` weights, as you `detached` the tensor `mu` which removes it from the [computation graph](https://youtu.be/MswxJw-8PvE) and so you do not see any updates in `self.action_head`.

Comment: Thats a great catch! thanks :)